# How to set ID of a XML-View in a component environment?

Tags: sapui5

I want to access a view's controller from a custom module with some utility functions. Basically you can do this that way:

```
var oController = sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview1").getController();
```

The problem is that the above coding will not work in a real environment because `__xmlview1`is dynamically created by the framework. So I tried to find a possibility to set the ID of the view during instantiation. The problem is - I could not find one:

Trying to give the view an ID in the view.xml file does not work:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="dividendgrowthtools.view.dividendcompare"
    id="testID"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    ...
```

Trying to set the ID in the router configuration of the component does not work either:

```
...
name: "Dividend Compare",
viewId: "test",
pattern: "Dividend-Compare",
target: "dividendcompare"
...
```

The problem is that I do not have direct control over the instantiation of the XML view - the component respectively the router does it.

So, is there a solution for that problem? Or at least a save way to get the view ID by providing the name of the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the SAPUI5 [EventBus](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.EventBus.html).

I am pretty sure, you want to let the controller to do something with the dividentcompare view. With the SAPUI5 Eventbus, you can publish actions from one controller to another witout braking MVC patterns.

In your dividendcompare.controller.js:

```
onInit : function() {
  var oEventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
  oEventBus.subscribe("MyChannel", "doStuff", this.handleDoStuff, this);
  [...]
},

handleDoStuff : function (oEvent) {
   var oView = this.getView(); 
   [...]
}
```

Now, in your anothercontroller.controller.js:

```
onTriggerDividendStuff : function (oEvent){
   var oEventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
   oEventBus.publish("MyChannel", "doStuff", { [optional Params] });
}
```

You are now able to get the view from the dividentcontroller in every case from every other controller of your app. You dont access the view directly, this would brake MVC patterns, but can pass options to its controller and do the handling there.